# Specific webpage's field fill up with autohotkey based pulover's macro creator

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I am fairly new to these, and been trying to make some automation script with help of pulover's macro creator which based on AHK. I am trying to put some IP values on specific device webpages, i already successful in inserting the value and it get changed. but as soon i hit "apply" it didn't recognized the given changed value. and it just came back to normal value.

The filed i am trying to edit have this code:

I am trying with this script: ie.document.getElementByID("61.0@s").Value := "192.168.192.18"
can somebody please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

AHK is using the IE web browser, and this could be one reason for the problem. And/or that the "AHK click" does not trigger some Javascript on the page correctly.

But you can automate the same task with [Kantu](https://kantu.io/kantu-web-automation). This web automation browser is based on Google Chromium and works well for automatically changing settings on my router's internal web pages.